# Xamarin Forms https with Client Certificates throws WebException

Tags: c#, ssl, https, xamarin.ios, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use client certificates for authentication in a Xamarin Forms App for iOS, but nothing seems to work. If I start the request the app waits to the default timeout of 100 seconds (I tried lowering it with HttpWebRequest.Timeout, but setting it seems to be ignored), after that, I get the following exception: **Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure**

The same code as a Windows console application works fine. Here some (simplified for readability) snippets to reproduce:

Client:

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(data, pwd);
var result = await ExecuteRequest("https://server/user.aspx", clientCertificate);

public static async Task<string> ExecuteRequest(Uri uri, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
{
    var hwr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    if (clientCertificate != null)
    {
        hwr.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
    }
    hwr.Method = "GET";
    try
    {
        var resWebResonse = await hwr.GetResponseAsync();
        var stream = resWebResonse.GetResponseStream(); 
        var sr = new StreamReader (stream);   
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Error executing Webrequest to {uri}: {ex}");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Server: user.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Principal" %>
<script runat="server">

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Regex userRegEx = new Regex("CN=(.*)@", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
                if (Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent)
                {
                    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
                    var identity = new GenericIdentity(cert.Subject, "ClientCertificate");
                    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
                    var m = userRegEx.Match (principal.Identity.Name);
                    Response.Write (m.Groups[1].Value);
                }
                else
                    Response.Write("No Client-Certificate");
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!(ex is System.Threading.ThreadAbortException))
                    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }    
</script>
```

This is the exception I keep getting:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags) [0x00017] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs:1773 
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x0009b] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:513 
--- End of inner exception stack trace 
---
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.EndReadOrWrite (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest& nestedRequest) [0x00056] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:335 
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:278 
at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00027] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:475 
--- End of inner exception stack trace 
---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00059] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1031 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] 
in <6314851f133e4e74a2e96356deaa0c6c>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown 
---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] 
in <6314851f133e4e74a2e96356deaa0c6c>:0 
at EWOIS.iOS.WebHelper+<ExecuteRequest>d__4.MoveNext () [0x0012e] in C:\xxxx\WebHelper.cs:70
```

- Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.5
- Xamarin 4.7.9.45
- Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Mac SDK 11.0.0.0
- Deployment Target iOS 9.3 (10.3 doesn´t work as well)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1
- IIS 7

I added a check for the server certificate (which is signed by our domain-CA) in AppDelegate.cs, it reports SslPolicyErrors.None

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    if (cert != null)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Servercertificate: {cert.Subject}, SSL-Policy-Errors: {sslPolicyErrors}");
    return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None; // return true does not work either (and is not recommended for security reasons)
}
```

The request works if I disable the certificate requirement on the web server, so the connection is working.

I even tried **System.Net.HttpClient**, but it throws a **NotImplementedException** when accessing the **ClientCertificate** Property :(

Now I am completely clueless what to try next... all other questions I found were a few years old and don´t offer any working solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a premium support call for that problem. I am not allowed to post code, but the solution was to use the native iOS classes instead of HttpClient or HttpWebRequest.

So in essence create an NSUrlSession, assign a custom implementation of INSUrlSessionDelegate to handle the DidReceiveChallenge event (to supply the client certificate) and then call the CreateDataTaskAsync method of the NSUrlSession.

Answer (score 2):

In your exception handler, it looks like you are not calling Response.End():

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!(ex is System.Threading.ThreadAbortException))
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

So if an exception is being thrown on the server side, it's possible that the response never gets sent to the client. I would recommend adding some server-side logging of the exception and see if anything useful is provided that way.

Also it looks like you verify certain fields of the client certificate, but as far as I can tell you don't verify that the client certificate is signed by a trusted root. You should make sure that's the case, or anyone can generate a self-signed certificate containing the username they want to impersonate and use that to trick your code, which would be a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: The Response.End is not actually needed for the response to end, I just wanted that the server does not add any html to the response. The server should not be the problem, since the clientcode works as a console-application, but not in Xamarin iOS. I will still test this on monday, I can't access my work from home. The cert-checking is missing, thanks for the advice

Comment: I added another Response.End to the catch-block, didn't change anything. I checked IIS-Logs, it seems that the request does not even hit the server, looks even more like a client side problem...

Answer (score 1):

I found several quesitons that point to problem with the Mono HTTP stack. It may help for resolving your problem: [How to validate SSL certificates when using HttpWebRequest](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1184815/how-to-stop-mono-from-preventing-authentication.html), [Urgent help needed: "error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure"](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63650/urgent-help-needed-error-getting-response-stream-readdone1-receivefailure). One of the possible ways is to use [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) that use platform-native HTTP client.

Also you have a mistake in the callback in [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx).
 [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a boolean value that determines whether the specified certificate is accepted for authentication. See more details in MSDN examples. Also try to read the question [How to validate SSL certificates when using HttpWebRequest](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/792342/how-to-validate-ssl-certificates-when-using-httpwe.html).

Comment: I found several threads about ModernHttpClient, the problem is all it does is setting native stuff up and using the normal HttpClient underneath. As mentioned in the question, HttpClient.ClientCertificate throws a NotImplementedException. I accidentially removed the callback-return value in the code-cleanup for posting, it would not compile without one. I tried both return true (not recommended for security reasons) and return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyError.None, neither of them works. I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: In this case try to check the correctness of your certificate on server and client side. Make sure that you have access to the full certificate including the private key. Certificate should be located in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store for the web server. I suppose [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582396/how-to-use-a-client-certificate-to-authenticate-and-authorize-in-a-web-api) may help you.

Comment: ClientCertificate.IsValid and HasPrivateKey are both true. The root CA exists on the device (Settings -> General -> Profiles -> (our MDM name) -> more details -> our root cert) and in the trusted roots on the webserver. The same certificate file can be used in a console application so it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you connect to the server over HTTPS without specifically adding the certificate?

Does the request get to the server alright? If so, the problem is probably in the decoding of the encrypted response. Are the certificates on the client and server the same?

Comment: Interesting, if i call https://servername/ without the certificate it works, if i call https://servername/test/test.aspx it does not (even after deactivating "require client cert" in ssl-settings)... I will test a bit more looking for a pattern