# Client certificate based authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates

Is there any way to authorize client **based on certificate** but access limited to specific controller or action in **WEB API**.

Suppose i have two controller having name A and B,
and have two clients X and Y.

Where i want like this,

Client X can access only Controller A and Client Y can access only Controller B based on the certificate issued to them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582396/how-to-use-a-client-certificate-to-authenticate-and-authorize-in-a-web-api Can you see this?

Comment: As per Ogglas answer, certificate is verifying based on the rootThumbprint and clientThumbprint value store in  app settings what if client certificate is expired and renewed? Is It same after renewing?

Comment: No, a thumbprint is not the same after renewing (either with the same key or a different key)

Comment: so is there is any way to validate certificate without storing the thumbprint in web config?